# How to get all 'href' with soup in python ? I try so many times but not work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, for-in-loop

How to get all  'href' with soup in python ? I try so many times but in vain.
Whatever I use 'soup.find' or 'soup.find_all' method to strugle for the 'href', it doesn't work.

python version:3.10

```
!pip install requests

import requests

import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
productlink = []
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
for page in range(1,2):
    url = "https://www.momomall.com.tw/s/103487/dcategory/all/3/{page}"
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for link in Soup.find_all('ul',class_="searchItem Stype"):
        print(len(link))
        Link = link.li.a
        LINK = Link.get('href')
        print(LINK)
        productlink.append(LINK)
print(productlink)
```

Comment: The page is dynamic. The content you're looking for doesn't exist in the loaded html. Instead javascript in the page loads the content from other urls. You'll need to figure what the other urls are for that content and then retrieve and parse those.

Comment: I figure out the element I find is in a script code

```

Comment: ```
<script>


var img_domain = 'https://img3.momomall.com.tw';

/* by jjsu 20160629 判斷是否有折後價  */
var discountPrice = 1530;
if (discountPrice == 1530) { 
 $('.prdDetailedArea .sellingPrice').html('<b>促銷價<span class="textEnding">：</span></b>$<span>1,530</span> <p><a href="/edm/Edm.jsp?npn=1vEIVviLCnjn&n=1" target="_blank"><b>約可獲得摩利點</b><i>：</i></a><b>15</b><span class="txt">點</></p>');
} else{ 
 $('.prdDetailedArea .sellingPrice').html('<b>折扣價<span class="textEnding">：</span></b>$<span>1,530</span> <p><a href="/edm/Edm.jsp?

```

Comment: I want to find the discountPrice. How could I find the element ? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

````
for page in range(1,2):
    url = "https://m.momomall.com.tw/m/store/DCategory.jsp?entp_code=103487&category_code=all&orderby=3&page={}".format(page)
    r = requests.get(url,headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    for goods_code in soup.select('a.nofollowBtn_star'):
        Goods_code = 'https://www.momomall.com.tw/s/103487/'+goods_code.get('goods_code')+'/'
        goodlink.append(Goods_code)

for URL in goodlink:
    R = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(R.text,"lxml")
    
    for dataprice in Soup.select('script'):
        import re
        discount_regex=re.compile('discountPrice = (\d{1,5})')
        print(re.search(discount_regex, dataprice).group(1))
    ```
````

Comment: After recoding that, it still shows TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

sorry i misunderstood totally your problem. `find_all` is not a very versatile tool and you were searching for the wrong `ul`

i barely changed your code but it seems to work now

```
import requests

import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
productlink = []
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
for page in range(1,2):
    url = f"https://www.momomall.com.tw/s/103487/dcategory/all/3/{page}"
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for link in Soup.select('ul#surveyContent > li > a[href]:first-of-type'):
        print(len(link))
        # ~ Link = link.li.a
        LINK = link.get('href')
        print(LINK)
        productlink.append(LINK)
print(productlink)
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. Is something wrong with the code ?

Comment: it does work. maybe you are doing something wrong